# How do I split a pem file?

Tags: split, certificate, apple-push-notifications, fastlane, pem

So [Fastlane pem](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/) generates a `.pem` file that includes both the certificate and the key. The system I need to upload it to takes two `.pem` files, one with the certificate and one with the key. It's trivial to manually split the file with a text editor, but is there a good command for splitting it in an automated fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a command to split the file into its two parts:

```
csplit $pemfile '/^-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----$/'
```

This leaves you with two files: `xx00` containing the certificate and `xx01` containing the key. Then all you need is a couple of `mv` commands to rename the files to something more appropriate.